# Get @push contents from Blade view in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**The problem:**

I have a laravel web route set up in a way, that if my `controller->action` handles a normal get request, it serves a fully rendered page, but if it handles an AJAX request, it returns only `@section('content')` of rendered view. I would like to retrieve the contents of the `@push('script')` directive for further processing.

**The question:**

Is it possible to get contents of `@push` from a partial view like the one in the example?

```php
// File: ExampleController.php

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function view(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $view     = View::make('example');
            $sections = $view->renderSections();

            return $sections['content']; //return only contents of @section('content')
        }
        return view('example'); //return fully rendered view with layout template.
    }
}
```

```php
<!-- File: example.blade.php -->

@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <div>
        <h1>My view</h1>
        <p>Some content of my view</p>
    </div>
@endsection

@push('script')
    <script>
        alert('Hey there stackoverflow!');
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$view->toHtml()`?

Comment: Because that would render the full view together with master layout and all the other sections. I only need to fetch the singular section. If i wanted to have the full layout fully rendered, i could have easily just used `return view('example');` in the first place. What i'm asking is, if there is a possibility to fetch contents of the `@push` from the particular view in a similar way as fetching the contents of `@section('content')` :)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you get the script from an ajax call it will get html code, it doesn't mean it will run the script. Also, @push doesn't add the content to the partial view directly, but to the referred stack 'script' in this case.

Comment: @phobia82 I understand that and know the inner workings of `@push` / `@stack` combo. I do not intend to include the contents of the `@push` in the ajax response I just need to find and easy way how to retrieve it without manually parsing the view :) If there is no view composer native way I will change the whole implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the view manually using the factory instance, look at render function: Illuminate\View\View::renderContents

```
if($request->ajax()) {
        $html = "";
        $view = View::make('example');
        $view->getFactory()->incrementRender();
        $view->getFactory()->callComposer($view);
        $html = $view->getEngine()->get($view->getPath(), $view->gatherData());
        $scriptTag = $view->getFactory()->yieldPushContent('script') // get script stack
        $view->getFactory()->decrementRender();
       ...
    }
```